# Why does order of declaration matter for setting up a tab host?

Tags: android

I am setting up a tab host for my application and I noticed that the order in which I declare each tab matters. When set up like this, my application quits unexpectedly, before reaching the activity:

```
    TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");

    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    spec1.setIndicator("Stop Watch");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3");

    th.addTab(spec1);
    th.addTab(spec2);
    th.addTab(spec3);
```

When set up like this, the application works just fine:

```
    TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("StopWatch");
    th.addTab(spec1);

    TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    th.addTab(spec2);

    TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec3.setIndicator("Add Tab");
    th.addTab(spec3);
```

Why does one work or not the other? Below, (some of) the console and logCat output are shown:
Console:

```
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.secondapp/com.example.secondapp.MangaList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b8a2a0)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
at com.example.secondapp.MangaList.<init>(MangaList.java:15)
```

Comment: I don't know anything about tabhosts but in your first bit of code you have three lines setting the indicator of spec1, which I believe is in error as you mean for the second and third line to be spec2 and 3. Maybe this is causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: please post your LogCat output of the case where you app crashes if you want to get a reliable answer.
P.S. this  is generally a good idea to add the logs to your question in case you tell us that "application quits unexpectedly"

Comment: Your console say "Activity not started". first close app and then try to install it.

Comment: well this is guessable that you are getting an NPE, so this log part isn't really useful. Please look for the `caused by:` line.
@KetanAhir this console output simply means that the app (which was already running) has not been re-installed, because no code changes were performed. So the `Activity` was just pushed to the top of the stack again, that's not an error

Comment: @KetanAhir that didn't change anything

Comment: @solalito It was only for console error that is your app was not running with new build.

Comment: @Droidman yeh..that is what I want to explain.

Comment: @solalito what code do you have at line 15 in `MangaList.java` class?